# installation error for elasticsearch on windows7

Tags: java, windows, elasticsearch

I have been trying to setup elasticsearch in windows7 machine by following `https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_installation.html`
I was able to download, unzip but when running `./elasticsearch`, I get the below error,

```
Error: Could not find or load main class 
org.elasticsearch.tools.JavaVersionChecker
Elasticsearch requires at least Java 8 but your Java version from C:\Program 
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131/bin/java does not meet this requirement
```

I have verified Java versions installed and they look fine,

`$ java -version`

```
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

`$ javac -version`
    javac 1.8.0_131

Can someone point out where I am wrong ?

Comment: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elastic-search-installation-error-in-windows/88169

Answer (score 1):

In run **Elasticsearch** in **Windows**, you should run with `elasticsearch.bat` not `./elasticsearch` directly:

> And now we are ready to start our node and single cluster (Windows users should run the elasticsearch.bat file):

Comment: `./elasticsearch` is a Linux script, though, so how would it run in windows anyway?

Comment: Hi @cricket_007, `C:\Program 
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131/bin/java` base on this `path` information(`/bin/java`), OP is running the **Linux** script on **Windows**,  Maybe he is using `mingw`, `cygwin` etc to run this **script**. so it better let OP run `./elasticsearch.bat` in the `cmd` or `powershell`.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you don't have right permissions. Try to set them to 774 and check again:

```
sudo chmod 774 -R elasticsearch-6.3.2/
```